# Having Two ObjectId in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get the matches array to contain the match and chatroom both of which are objectId with reference to different Schema. But when I log the match in a get operation I cannot understand what is logged in the matches section can someone help me with this.

[image]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema;

var match = new Schema({
        match:{
            type: ObjectId,
            ref:'User'
        },
        chatroom:{
            type:ObjectId,
            ref:'Chatroom'
        }
    });
const matchList = new Schema({
    user:{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    },
    likeSent:[
        {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref:'User'   
        },{
            timestamp:true
        }
    ],
    likeRecieve:[
        {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref:'User'   
        },{
            timestamp:true
        }
    ],
    matches:[match]    
},{
    timestamp:true
});

const MatchList = mongoose.model('Match',matchList);

module.exports = MatchList;
```

Comment: what's the log and error you receive?

Comment: it not an error but the matches section(in the image given ) it gives an output i dont understand

Comment: your matches is  declared as an array of match.  Match itself is an object, containing subelements.  Show your insertion code, and your logging code where you do the "GET" please.